# How to downgrade Ubuntu Node from 12.11 to 12.04 LTS on AWS?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04

Our node initially was running with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on AWS. But somehow the OS was bumped up to 12.11 (on development branch) by itself. How can we downgrade the node to back to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and keep the OS for as long as we like?

Is there a configuration on AWS console that allows us to change OS version?

Comment: The only way it would have been upgraded is if it was done within the instance itself. Not sure ubuntu provides a way to downgrade.

Comment: Do you mean upgrading through the SSH connection? Somehow the OS was upgraded but we did not do it. This is something worries us. This is production machine.

Comment: EC2 is just infrastructure, it does not have visibility inside your instance. I think the only way you can downgrade is to relaunch a new instance.

Comment: @datasage, do you know why the node OS was upgraded by itself? We are concerned about it because it is production machine.

Comment: Its not something within AWS that would have done it. I would suggest checking logs to see if anyone ran an upgrade command. Do you have any systems that are automatically updating/installing patches?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not designed for roll backs. If you are on the LTS branch and your `sources.list` file has not been altered and `dist-upgrade` has not been run, there should be no reason for the system to upgrade.

Your best route is to create a new instance or, if you've created a snapshot (with EBS) recovering from it.